# Basic normalmap material does not render smooth in Blender 2.93.1 eevee

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

I have this normalmap material that renders smooth in eevee in Blender 2.92.0 but doesn't in Blender 2.93.1

What is needed to do in order to make the material render smooth in Blender 2.93.1?

The .blend file (Saved in Blender2.93.1) is provided below, and some screenshots as well.

[image: Image in Blender 2.92.0]

[image: Image in Blender 2.93.1]

[image: Nodes]

Google drive link for the .blend file (Saved in Blender2.93.1):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AfRX1_uSktKyhhep-o5AGKZ2eTi44gqn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: First thing I would try, is changing the Normal Map image texture's _Color Space_ from _sRGB_ to _Non-Color_. (This is proper convention for normal maps).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any image texture that is not used as a color data should have its `Color Space` set to `Non-Color`:

[image: non-color]

This is required for its data to be interpreted correctly.